# a very strange sentence. please help to understand

Tags: phrases, translation, phrase-meaning

There is a book by Galina Demykina "The lost girl and the scallywags" (a Russian one, translated into English, 1977)
and there is a very strange sentence:
"Zoya saw nothing save thick, ever so thick bushes."
I cannot undestand it. It must mean that Zoya could see nothing, but very thick bushes.
So, is there a real English word-construction "save ..., ever so ..." or it is just a made-up by the translator?

Comment: The word *save* can indeed mean *but* or *except*. The *ever so thick* isn't connected to the *save*, it's just an elaboration on *thick*.

Comment: Consider _ever so thick_ a parenthetical addition: “Zoya saw nothing save thick (ever so thick) bushes”.